# Parse text using scanner & useDelimiter / right regula expression

Tags: java, regex, date, java.util.scanner

I want calculate the days between two dates but I have problems with parsing my inputstream ...

It works fine if I type my date like "22 1 2013", but I struggle with:

22.1.2013

22-01-2013

01/22/2013

unfortunately I don't know much about regular expressions and all my tests with useDelimiter failed; maybe you can help me (I'm only allowed to import the Scanner-class):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewDateDifference {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int day1, day2, month1, month2, year1, year2; 

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("First Date:\t");

        day1 = scan.nextInt(); 
    month1 = scan.nextInt(); 
    year1 = scan.nextInt();


    /**    scan = new Scanner(scan.next()).useDelimiter("\\.");
        if ( scan.hasNextInt() ) {
            day1 = scan.nextInt();
        }
        if ( scan.hasNextInt() ) {
            month1 = scan.nextInt();
        }
        if ( scan.hasNextInt() ) {
            year1 = scan.nextInt(); 
        }
        scan.close(); **/



        System.out.print("Second Date:\t");
        day2 = scan.nextInt(); 
        month2 = scan.nextInt();
        year2 = scan.nextInt(); 

        int diff = calculateDays(year2, month2, day2) - calculateDays(year1, month1, day1);
        System.out.println("Days: " + Math.abs(diff));

}

public static int calculateDays(int year, int month, int day) {

    int[] dayTillMonth = {0, 31, 61, 92, 122, 153, 184, 214, 245, 275, 306, 337};

    if(month < 3) {
        year -= 1; month += 9;
    } else {
        month -= 3;
    }
    return year * 365 + year/4 - year/100 + year/400 + dayTillMonth[month] + day;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this delimiter

```
scan.useDelimiter("[\\s.\\-/]+");
```

It will set up as delimiter one or more of characters that are either

- `\\s` whitespace like in `\r\n`
- `.`
- `-`
- `/`

Comment: Thx; Can I check somehow if the delimniter will use / ? Cause in US dates its MM/DD/YYYY and in German dates DD MM YYYY ...

Comment: @user3025448 I doubt you will have access to found delimiter since it is character that should be omitted. Maybe use different approach like read entire line, check what character is on position 2 (assuming that index of first character is 0), next split this line using `[\\s.\\-/]` (this way you will get array of Strings like `["DD", "MM", "YYYY"]` and then just convert each element of that array to integer, like for days `int day = Integer.parseInt(array[0])`.

Comment: hm I tried to fix it the easy way with a little if-command, but it doensn't seem to work. Do you know why?: 
`String eingabe1 = scan.toString();        
if (eingabe1.contains("/")) {
 ...
}`

Comment: @user3025448 What do you think `scan.toString();` should do? I suspect that you want to use `scan.readLine();`

Answer (score 0):

uncomment the commented section in your code, and use the following:

```
.useDelimiter("."); //for 22.1.2013
.useDelimiter("\\"); //for 22\1\2013
.useDelimiter("/"); //for 22/1/2013 (most used i think)
.useDelimiter("-"); //for 22-1-2013
```